# Critical Point Question

Tags: calculus

For a coordinate to be a critical point is it required that all partial derivatives are zero. This is probably a very obvious question but I am not sure.

I mean, lets say $$f(x,y)= e^{65x-x^32+y^72-5y+6x+7x^2y+4}$$

just as a random example.

do you have to find just when $df/dx=0$ and $df/dy=0$ or also when $d^2f/dx^2=0$ etc, and if not, what do those tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the points where both $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=0$. That is according to the definition of [critical point for functions of several variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)#Several_variables).

The second derivatives are not needed, though they may be needed to tell if a given critical point is a maximum, minimum, or saddle point.